# NextJS Pages add files on runtime

Tags: next.js

So I have an older NextJS project with /pages.
I want the user to be able to upload files (eg. pictures), but NextJS shows a 404 until it gets restarted.
Is there a way to automatically add them on runtime?

The files will all end up in `/public/`
I am using `<Image/>` to show some of these files.
I am using `Cache-Control` with the following settings `public, s-maxage=20, stale-while-revalidate=120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public` directory is only for static assets that will be used only during build time. you cannot add files to it during runtime. the reason is that the NextJS is a serverless framework which means that it is planned to be deployed on multiple servers at the same time. so if you try to add files manually during runtime, the files will be added to only one of the servers and not all of them.

The solution is to use cloud storages (e.g. [s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage) or azure) which provide a storage that you can manage files (CRUD) with their API.

If you plan to deploy on Vercel, keep in mind that Vercel has its own [cloud storage](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-blob) too (currently it is in beta version which has some limitations).

you can choose your cloud storage based on your needs and budget

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to implement CRUD?

Comment: @Florian-Mahlberg that's not that simple to put a CRUD example of a cloud storage as it needs configuration and must be implemented based on the framework you are using and your needs.

Comment: A GitHub [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12656#issuecomment-641025110)  made a custom solution. Would that work as well?

Comment: @Florian-Mahlberg custom server has its own side cons (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) . besides that, I don't think it solves the file-per-instance problem. moreover...! uploading files affects performance a lot. uploading files to a separate server is a better idea, unless you want to do it just for a hubby or a practice project